# How can I set a parameter that accepts an object to be declared later on?

Tags: c#, object

As I made my game, I stumbled upon a slight problem. I have a method Attack() that must execute when my character attacks an enemy. For example:

```
public override void Attack(Object theEnemy)
{          
      theEnemy.Health = theEnemy.Health - this.attack
}
```

Example: I attack an Elf. The Elf object needs to be the parameter, the problem is that the parameter is looking for Object, not Elf. Same goes for if I want to attack other enemy objects such as Orc, Dwarf etc. I need the parameter to be able to accept any object. Is it possible?

Comment: use an interface that is implemented by all your enemy creatures?

Answer (score 7):

You can use interface in this case e.g.:

```
interface IEnemy
{
    void TakeDamage(int attackPower);
}

public Elf: IEnemy
{
    // sample implementation
    public void TakeDamage(int attackPower)
    {
        this.Health -= attackPower - this.Defense;
    }
}

// later on use IEnemy, which is implemented by all enemy creatures
void Attack(IEnemy theEnemy)
{          
      theEnemy.TakeDamage(attack)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like anything that can be "attacked" must implement an interface giving access to the required properties and/or methods.

So for example you could do

```
public interface IAttackable
{
    void ReduceHealth(int amount);
}
```

Then implement it for any creature which is attackable - ie, Elf

```
public class Elf : IAttackable
{
    public void ReduceHealth(int amount)
    {
        this.Health -= amount;
    }
}
```

Then usage would be

```
public override void Attack(IAttackable theEnemy)
{          
      theEnemy.ReduceHealth(this.attack);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interface that each enemy object implements or you could create a base class that each enemby object is based on.

```
public interface IEnemyCreature{

void ReduceHealth(int Amount)

}

public Elf: IEnemyCreature{
...
}
```

Edit - WalkHard has described the code better than I 9-)

Answer (score 1):

Best is to Seperate the Concerns and use OOP concepts. 
Use Interface.

```
interface IGameMethods
{
    void Attack(int yourValueForAttackMethod);
}
```

for implementation

```
public Elf: IGameMethods
{
    // implementation of IGameMethods
}
```